# Manhwa about a weak brother who defeated a red dragon and was given a chance to travel back in time

Tags: story-identification, manga

I think it starts with two brothers. The weak brother defeated a red dragon and was given a chance to travel back in time. I think the young brother was a leader of a guild. It's a fantasy manhwa, it has magic and I think one of the young brother's friends was a blue haired girl who use ice magic

Answer (score 0):

My S Class Hunters. I think it matches your criteria.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit] this to explain *how* it matches the criteria?